# Acionar uma função de uma aba a partir de outro Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

A comunicação dentre telas é imprescindíveis em uma aplicação.

Neste caso eu estou tentando realizar uma pesquisa a partir de uma SearchDelegate

Porém quando faço a retorno do SearchDelegate não consigo me comunicar com  a aba interna

Por exemplo:

**Home.dart**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  List<String> _itensMenu = ["Sair"]; 
  _escolherMenuItem(String itemEscolhido) {
    switch (itemEscolhido) {
      case "Sair":
        _sairDoApp();
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
             actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () async {
                String res = await showSearch(
                    context: context, delegate: CustomSearchDelegate());
                AbaProdutos().pesquisar(res);
              }),
          PopupMenuButton(
              onSelected: _escolherMenuItem,
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return _itensMenu.map((String item) {
                  return PopupMenuItem<String>(value: item, child: Text(item));
                }).toList();
              })
        ],
        )
      )
  }
}
```

Perceba que estou chamando a seguinte função: `AbaProdutos().pesquisar(res)`

**AbaProdutos.dart**

```
class AbaProdutos extends StatefulWidget {
  pesquisar(param) => createState().pesquisar(param);

  @override
  _AbaProdutosState createState() => _AbaProdutosState();
}

class _AbaProdutosState extends State<AbaProdutos> {
    
  pesquisar(param) {
    print("pesquisar param " + param);
    if (this.mounted) {
      print("montado ");
      setState(() {
        _strPesquisar = param;
        _paginaAtual = 1;
        _obterProdutos();
      });
    } else {
      print("não montado");
    }
  }

}
```

Até consigo chegar nessa função. Estou fazendo o teste se está montado.

Porém nunca entra dentro do `if( this.mounted )`

E quando eu tiro o `if( this.mounted )` ele dá o seguinte erro

> E/flutter (32036): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor:
> _AbaProdutosState#06c34(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted) E/flutter (32036): This happens when you call setState() on a
> State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget
> tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor,
> since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially
> created.

**A pergunta:**

Como fazer com a função de pesquisa do Home funcione dentro da aba sem problemas?

Ou mesmo se tiver como eu ficar ouvindo mudanças da variável do home dentro da aba

Answer (score 0):

- Explicando o problema:

Você está fazendo uma verificação `if (this.mounted)`. Como o nome diz, essa propriedade explicita se o Widget em questão **está inserido** na árvore de Widgets ou não.

A documentação pode ser lida [aqui](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) (em inglês).

> Whether this State object is currently in a tree.
>
> After creating a State object and before calling initState,[...]

Isto é, apenas após a criação do objeto de estado e inserção desse widget na árvore essa variável será considerada como verdadeira.

Da forma que você apresentou, esse widget não está inserido em nenhum lugar. Você simplesmente cria uma nova instância dele com `AbaProdutos()`. Esta instância recém criada dentro do `onPressed` não está sendo exibida. Por isso que se você verifica se ela está exibida, a resposta vai ser "não" e você não entrará no `if`.

Provavelmente você tem uma outra instância dessa "aba" em algum outro lugar. Pela sua pergunta não pude perceber aonde. E você quer chamar o método de `pesquisar` dessa instância específica.

Outro problema feito por você tem o mesmo princípio. Quando você faz:

```
pesquisar(param) => createState().pesquisar(param);
```

Você está chamando a função pesquisar de uma varíavel de estado nova, que não é aquela que está associada ao Widget. `createState()` chama o contrutor dessa classe. Não acredito que isso deva funcionar.

- Estratégias para solução:

  - Usar uma solução de gerenciamento de estado e injeção de dependência:

O *correto* para este caso é melhor gerenciar seu estado. Como você disse na pergunta, a comunicação entre as telas é primordial em um aplicativo, e para isso você precisa de uma solução robusta e concreta para tal. Fazer gambiarras como a citada abaixo, (ou outras não citadas) apenas aumenta a possibilidade de erro, a ineficiência do aplicativo, e impede a escalabilidade do projeto. Do jeito que está mostrado na pergunta, você aparentemente não usa nenhum tipo de gerenciamento de estado.

Os tipos de soluções de gerenciamento de estado são muitos, e um bom compilado deles pode ser achado no site oficial do Flutter, [aqui](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). Isso é material para muitas e muitas perguntas e seria impossível responder sucintamente aqui. Nesse próprio site o primeiro link é uma [introdução](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) para gerenciamento de estado. O recomendado pela Google é o [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) e eu acredito que ele é o mais simples e direto de entender.

Sugiro estudar essa parte e analisar o melhor caso para sua aplicação em específico.

Deixo aqui também uma solução não recomendável, e mais gambiarra por motivos didáticos.

- Salvar a instância da aba em uma variável (**Não recomendável**):

A primeira coisa que vem a mente quando se entende esse problema é salvar uma referência a essa aba, e chamar a função utilizando essa referência. Já vi pessoas que inventam um monte de métodos estáticos e chamam apenas eles (Como se seu projeto inteiro fosse feito por *Singletons*). Isso vai funcionar, porém você perde muitas vantagens sobre como Flutter vai gerenciar sua árvore de Widgets e os seus respectivos objetos de estado. Mas a princípio resolveria seu problema e talvez em um aplicativo pequeno as consequências não seriam tão visíveis.